# How to get all classes that contain icon-(icon-name) and append <span class="glyp + icon-name"></span>

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('a[class*=icon-]').append("<span class='glyphicon glyph'></span>");
```

With the code i have now i can turn:

```
<a class="btn icon-edit"><a>
```

into

```
<span class="glyphicon glyph><span>
<a class="btn icon-edit %>
```

But i want to append the selected class "icon-edit" to the span class. Because i want something like this:

```
var icon-name = $('a[class*=icon-]')
$('a[class*=icon-]').append("<span class='glyphicon glyph + icon-name'></span>");
```

To get this result:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit><span>
<a class="btn icon-edit %>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y9uvj91g/

Comment: Since there may be more than a single class you have to make a iteration that calls a function for each match which identifies the right one and then creates a fresh span tag which you can append.

Comment: Can you fiddle your code: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$('a[class*=icon-]').before(function () {
    //create a span for each anchor matching the selector with the class name
    return $('<span />', {
        'class': 'glyphicon glyphicon-' +this.className.match(/icon-([^\s]+)/)[1]
    }).get();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pcp167Lz/)

Answer (score 0):

"" this was missing. Its working now try it.

```
$('a[class*="icon-"]').append("<span class='glyphicon glyph'></span>");
```

Comment: Sorry I did not get you, what are you saying. 
You can also the working fiddle Link : [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mayurRahul/y21pxhck/)

Comment: The question is about creating a span with a class that matches the class in the anchor tag. _Not_ the literal class `glyph`. See the other answer. So this is _not_ an answer to the question. I suggest you delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also, just for an option.

```
$(function(){
 var icon_name = $('a[class*=icon-]');
 var i_val = icon_name.attr('class').substr(icon_name.attr('class').indexOf("-") + 1);

icon_name.before("<span class='glyphicon glyph-"+i_val+"'></span>"); 
});
```